# Responsive Twitter Bootstrap's incompatibility with jCarouselLite

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, jcarousellite

I came over a issue while using jCarouselLite with Bootstrap responsive.

The plugin initialization is basic:

```
$("#slider").jCarouselLite({
    auto: 800,
    speed: 1000,
    visible: 4
});
```

I have created a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/BcqXE/4/show/) where everything is working very fine, but when you resize the browser to a point where a grid column spans over full width, you will notice that the jCarouselLite elements starts acting funny.

> **The elements width are supersized.**

Same can be viewed from the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/BcqXE/4/) version too.

I have attached a image showing the size:
[image: Supersized jCarousel Elements]

Any fix?

Comment: Have you thought about using another slider? There's one that comes packed with Twitter Bootstrap?  I left an answer around a bunch of other options for sliders a little earlier http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14762770/responsive-jquery-ui-slider/14763315#14763315

Answer (score 0):

Since jCarouselLite isn't really intended as a responsive slider, your best bet would be to try an alternative which is more specifically set up for a responsive layout (and which will detect and react to viewport changes).

There's one [specifically for Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel) that might suit well?

Saving that, the alternatives that I tend to use are:

- [RoyalSlider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) - it's paid-for but featureful!
- [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) - free and released under the [WTFPL license](http://www.wtfpl.net/), this is the one I most commonly use now.  It's very slightly more complex than RoyalSlider but ideal for use in commercial applications and very easy to extend.